# CSS3 Multiple Columns and position:absolute

Tags: css, css-multicolumn-layout

I'm using CSS3 Multiple Columns. Inner elements have position:relative and can contain arrows with position:absolute.

```
.clm3{
  -webkit-column-count: 3;
  -moz-column-count: 3;
  column-count: 3;
  -webkit-column-gap: 0;
  -moz-column-gap: 0;
  column-gap: 0;
}
```

**Problem:** CSS3 column cut off part of arrow with position:absolute.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/k4ucr72h/

Comment: What do you expect to happen?

Comment: I expect that absolute position element will be completely visible and located above all elements without position:absolute

Comment: Yes but absolutely positioned elements are still bound to the borders of their relative container. In this case your labels (`.custCheck`) have `position: relative` and that means that the "arrows" won't be able to exceed their limit. I suggest you take the arrows outside of the list, or remove the relative position from the labels, and then locate the arrows with JS.

Comment: I don't understand. Usually I can move my absolute position element wherever I want outside position:relative parent.

Comment: You can do it, like shown in [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/gp07fys9/). Unless the relative container has `overflow: hidden` like shown in [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/gp07fys9/1/). I guess the browser simply (and quite logically) makes sure that every column will behave as if it has `overflow: hidden`

Comment: BTW what I've written before about the labels being the boundaries is wrong. The column is the boundary of course. But as I said, if you make the arrows absolute position while the labels won't be, you'll be able to position the arrows where you want

Answer (score 11):

Try to use this on `li` items in your column:

```
.clm3 li {
  -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; 
}
```

Also add `z-index` to `.countArrow` class:

```
.countArrow {
  z-index: 1
}
```

Comment: -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;  seems do the trick. Thx.